# L2 convergence subsequence and conditional expectation

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, conditional-expectation

Suppose we have two sequence of random variables $(X_n)$ and $(Y_n)$, such that

- $Y_n\rightarrow Y \quad \text{in} \quad \mathcal{L}_2,$ and
- $X_n=\mathbb{E}(Y_n \mid X_n),$  for each $n$.

I am wondering if there is a subsequence $(X_{n_k})$ that converges in $\mathcal{L}_2$. I suspect one can construct a counterexample to this statement, but have not been able to do so myself.

Comment: Since $X_n=\mathbb E[Y_n-Y\mid X_n]+\mathbb E[Y\mid X_n]$, it suffices to deal with the case where $Y_n=Y$.  Let $Z_n:=\mathbb E[Y\mid X_n]$. The sequence $(Z_n^2)$ is uniformly integrable and admits a weakly convergent sequence (in $L^1$), But I do not know the final answer.

Comment: Yes, the only issue is to find a a.s. convergence subsequence. Right now I am only able to find convex combinations of $(X_n)$ that converges strongly in $L^2$.